# UPS Auto Shutdown (Socomec 3KVA RT)

Tags: firefox

Can Socomec support Ubuntu 2.6 for Auto Shutdown?

Where can I locate the instruction for set up?

Comment: I think he/she's talking about this http://www.socomec.com/characteristics-software-uni-vision-pro_en.html, but that's something to ask the vendor of the hardware.